# XCode iOS6 CoreData NSFetchedResultsController can't fetch new data

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, sqlite, core-data

I have this piece of code:

```
- (void) fetchRecordsStaringFrom:(double)start limit:(double)limit whereFields:(NSArray*)whereFields haveValues:(NSArray*)whereValues sortBy:(NSString*)sortField ascending:(BOOL)isascending delegateEvent:(BOOL)delegateEvent{
NSFetchRequest *_fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[_fetchRequest setEntity:self.entityDescription];
// Create the sort descriptors array.
// Default sort is ID
if (sortField == NULL) {
    sortField = @"id";
}
NSSortDescriptor *authorDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:sortField ascending:NO];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:authorDescriptor, nil];
[_fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
if (whereFields != Nil && whereValues != Nil && ([whereFields count] == [whereValues count])) {
    NSMutableString *predicateString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@""];
    for (int index = 0; index < [whereFields count]; index++) {
        [predicateString appendFormat:@"%@==%@", whereFields[index], whereValues[index]];
        if (index < [whereFields count] - 1) {
            [predicateString appendString:@" AND "];
        }
    }
    // Delete old cache to make sure always get new data
    [NSFetchedResultsController deleteCacheWithName:nil];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:predicateString];
    [_fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
} else {
}
self.fetchRequest = _fetchRequest;
self.fetchResultController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:self.fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.context sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
self.fetchResultController.delegate = self;
NSError *_error;
if (delegateEvent) {
    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(CoreDataEntityRequestStartEvent:::)]) {
        [self.delegate CoreDataEntityRequestStartEvent:self :self.fetchRequest :self.fetchResultController];
    }
    if (![self.fetchResultController performFetch:&_error]) {
        if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(CoreDataEntityRequestErrorEvent::)]) {
            [self.delegate CoreDataEntityRequestErrorEvent:self :_error];
        }
    } else {
        if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(CoreDataEntityRequestSuccessEvent:::)]) {
            [self.delegate CoreDataEntityRequestSuccessEvent:self :self.fetchRequest :self.fetchResultController];
        }
    }
    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(CoreDataEntityRequestEndEvent:::)]) {
        [self.delegate CoreDataEntityRequestEndEvent:self :self.fetchRequest :self.fetchResultController];
    }
} else {
    [self.fetchResultController performFetch:&_error];
}
}
```

When performed, the method above will get data from SQLITE database, no problem here,
but when i change the SQLITE using external SQLITE editor or by other means, then perform again using same arguments, it can't get new data and keep resulting old data, unless i restart the App.

I looking here and there and it might be because cache, but as you can see, i already clear the cache, but still can't get new data.

---

Thanks for your response,
The answer is: Just for testing,

This is the actual case:
for example, in screen UITableView, get data from internet (the data is not complete), store it in database then load and display in view, then when one cell tapped, will get complete data from internet for selected cell, update the database, and display it in other screen. when return to UItableView, and reload from database, the recordset should be changed due previous update, so when user re-tap at same cell, there is no need to get data from internet, since we already have completed data for selected cell. But.... as i explained in question above, NSFetchResultController didn't give new data, even after the SQLITE file is updated!

Comment: I don't understand, Why you are changing the database externally using some third party database editor?

Comment: I updated the question, see above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, sorry for the long break, this is how i solve my problem for anyone who encounter this problem in the future, all credits goes to everyone here, thanks.

When perform fetch request make sure to delete the old cache

```
[NSFetchedResultsController deleteCacheWithName:nil];
```

Then for all fetched object in fetchResultController, call refreshObject with option mergeChanges YES

```
for (int i = 0; i < [[self.fetchResultController fetchedObjects] count]; i++) {
[self.context refreshObject:[[self.fetchResultController fetchedObjects] objectAtIndex:i] mergeChanges:YES];
}
```

this will ensure you to get new data every time fetch request is performed

Answer (score 1):

Core Data tracks entity objects in memory but lazy loads the actual attribute values. The act of lazy loading is called faulting. If you modify an attribute value directly in the store and then a fault is fired for the corresponding managed object, the changed values will be loaded into memory. Managed objects will then persist in memory until no longer needed. Core Data assumes it has control of the store and will not attempt to load the managed object attribute values again until the object is invalidated and another fault is fired for it. So if you change a value after a managed object has already been populated for the record, the changes won't immediately appear. You will need to understand your managed object behavior and lifetimes to work out when to expect the changes to be represented in memory.

Also be cautious not to make changes directly to the store while an app is running and then interact with the app in a way that commits changes to the database. If Core Data needs to update the record that you had modified, it will assume (rightly so under normal conditions) that it has exclusive control and will overwrite your sneaky changes with data from the in-memory managed objects.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your answer. 
just as i explained, i directly change the data just for testing, the problem is still occurred even i update the data using code, so it just for easy changed.

so how to prevent this faulting thing? i want the core data to always read from actual database.

Comment: You are welcome. if you think that i have answered your question, please accept it to help others who have the same problem. Thanks

Comment: i don't know if it's possible to change the behavior. The sample and safe solution is to re-lunch your application after each modification of your SQLite database.

Comment: Thereis no way i can tell user to restart the application each time there is changed in database isn't it?

Comment: My response is for "i am changing SQLITE by using external editor". If you are changing the SQLite by an editor, you can not seen the changes automatically, you should re-lunch your application.